# Adjust XML output in GraphML

Tags: markup, xml-namespaces, custom-tag, graphml

Do you think I can adjust the xml output from GraphML?

In the [GraphML wiki](https://github.com/tinkerpop/blueprints/wiki/GraphML-Reader-and-Writer-Library) the tags seem to be fixed:

```
<graphml>
  <graph>
    <node>
      <data></data>
    </node>
    <edge>
      <data></data>
    </edge>
  </graph>
</graphml>
```

I saw that you can change the tag attributes. 
Do you think I could customize the tags itself to something like `<car></car>`?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to add new elements, you would have to modify [the DTD](http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/specification/dtd.html). In that case, your data would no longer be GraphML, but your own standard due to the [DTD customization](http://www.htmlhelp.com/tools/validator/customdtd.html). Here is the GraphML DTD:

```
<!-- ====================================================================== -->
<!-- file: graphml.dtd ====================================================== 

  This is the Document Type Definition for the release candidate of 
  GraphML version 1.0 and represents a (necessarily) looser specification 
  than the corresponding XML Schema.  It's use is discouraged, though it
  may be necessary for some systems.

  Usage:

            SYSTEM "http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/dtds/1.0rc/graphml.dtd"

            xmlns="http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns/1.0rc"

    ====================================================================== -->

<!-- ===============================================================-->
<!--Parameter entity for data content -->
<!--================================================================-->

<!ENTITY % GRAPHML.data.content "(#PCDATA)">

<!-- ===============================================================-->
<!--Parameter entities for attribute list extensions -->
<!--================================================================-->

<!ENTITY % GRAPHML.graphml.attrib "">
<!ENTITY % GRAPHML.locator.attrib "">
<!ENTITY % GRAPHML.graph.attrib "">
<!ENTITY % GRAPHML.node.attrib "">
<!ENTITY % GRAPHML.port.attrib "">
<!ENTITY % GRAPHML.edge.attrib "">
<!ENTITY % GRAPHML.hyperedge.attrib "">
<!ENTITY % GRAPHML.endpoint.attrib "">
<!ENTITY % GRAPHML.key.attrib "">
<!ENTITY % GRAPHML.data.attrib "">
<!ENTITY % GRAPHML.default.attrib "">

<!--============================================================-->
<!--Attributes used by each GRAPHML element-->
<!--============================================================-->

<!ENTITY % GRAPHML.common.attrib
           ""
>

<!--================================================================-->
<!--the graphml elements-->
<!--================================================================-->

<!ELEMENT data  %GRAPHML.data.content;>
<!ATTLIST data 
                key            IDREF   #REQUIRED
                id             ID      #IMPLIED
                %GRAPHML.data.attrib;
                %GRAPHML.common.attrib;
>

<!ELEMENT default  %GRAPHML.data.content;>
<!ATTLIST default 
                %GRAPHML.default.attrib;
                %GRAPHML.common.attrib;
>

<!ELEMENT key (desc?,default?)>
<!ATTLIST key 
              id  ID       #REQUIRED
              for (graph|node|edge|hyperedge|port|endpoint|all) "all"
              %GRAPHML.key.attrib;
              %GRAPHML.common.attrib;
>   

<!ELEMENT graphml  (desc?,key*,(data|graph)*)>
<!ATTLIST graphml  
                   %GRAPHML.graphml.attrib;
                   %GRAPHML.common.attrib;
>

<!ELEMENT graph    (desc?,(((data|node|edge|hyperedge)*)|locator))>
<!ATTLIST graph    
                   id       ID           #IMPLIED
                   edgedefault (directed|undirected) #REQUIRED
                   %GRAPHML.graph.attrib;
                   %GRAPHML.common.attrib;
>   

<!ELEMENT node   (desc?,((((data|port)*,graph?))|locator))>
<!ATTLIST node   
                 id        ID      #REQUIRED
                 %GRAPHML.node.attrib;
                 %GRAPHML.common.attrib;
>

<!ELEMENT port (desc?,(data|port)*)>
<!ATTLIST port
               name    NMTOKEN  #REQUIRED
               %GRAPHML.port.attrib;
               %GRAPHML.common.attrib;
>


<!ELEMENT edge (desc?,data*,graph?)>
<!ATTLIST edge 
               id         ID           #IMPLIED
               source     IDREF        #REQUIRED
               sourceport NMTOKEN      #IMPLIED
               target     IDREF        #REQUIRED
               targetport NMTOKEN      #IMPLIED
               directed   (true|false) #IMPLIED
               %GRAPHML.edge.attrib;
               %GRAPHML.common.attrib;
>

<!ELEMENT hyperedge  (desc?,(data|endpoint)*,graph?)>
<!ATTLIST hyperedge 
                    id     ID      #IMPLIED
                    %GRAPHML.hyperedge.attrib;
                    %GRAPHML.common.attrib;
>

<!ELEMENT endpoint (desc?)>
<!ATTLIST endpoint 
                   id    ID       #IMPLIED
                   node  IDREF    #REQUIRED
                   port  NMTOKEN  #IMPLIED
                   type  (in|out|undir) "undir"
                   %GRAPHML.endpoint.attrib;
                   %GRAPHML.common.attrib;
>

<!ELEMENT locator EMPTY>
<!ATTLIST locator 
                   xmlns:xlink   CDATA   #FIXED  "http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/PR-xlink-20001220/"
                   xlink:href     CDATA    #REQUIRED
                   xlink:type     (simple) #FIXED    "simple"
                   %GRAPHML.locator.attrib;
                   %GRAPHML.common.attrib; 
>

<!ELEMENT desc (#PCDATA)>
<!ATTLIST desc %GRAPHML.common.attrib;>
```

**References**

- [Comparison between XML to SVG Transformation Mechanisms](http://www.svgopen.org/2003//papers/ComparisonXML2SVGTransformationMechanisms/)